# Different style of navigation - Phone vs Tablet?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am fairly good in fragments API, I know how to create master/detail pattern on phone/tablet.
**But how would I create a different style of navigation in phones and tablets?**

The most obvious example would be swiping tabs on the phone and somekind tablet layout with all the fragments layed out inside, no swiping tabs.

Is there some elegant way of doing this other than giant if statement?

[image]

**//EDIT**

So what would you do, as I presumed, is to create create two layouts (phone - view pager / tablet - three static fragments) and in activity's onCreate check for something in the layout to figure out wether youre in phone or tablet. **Then just initialize the tabs navigation / or not if youre in tablet.** That should work.

*CODE SNIPPETS FROM IO 2012 APP*

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    if (mViewPager != null) {
        // Phone setup
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new HomePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(R.string.title_my_schedule)
                .setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(R.string.title_explore)
                .setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(R.string.title_stream)
                .setTabListener(this));

        homeScreenLabel = getString(R.string.title_my_schedule);

    } else {
        //Tablet setup
        mExploreFragment = (ExploreFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_tracks);
        mMyScheduleFragment = (MyScheduleFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_my_schedule);
        mSocialStreamFragment = (SocialStreamFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_stream);
    }
}
```

Any of you guys that already have tabs navigation on phone, please consider implementing this on the tablet, if it works for you design-wise. You already have fragments api ready, so there's no excuse, really.

Comment: You mean to accomidate the difference in screen size? i.e. on a phone I need navigation because I cannot fit all the fragments on one screen but on a tablet, where I have more space I can see 2 or 3 at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at the 2012 I/O app from Roman Nurik, which switches navigation/layout pretty much with every possible combination of size and orientation;

http://code.google.com/p/iosched/

Comment: dont worry ill do when I get home, I want to check it out first to pull out more comprehensive answer from the code for others to see